# Find parent which contains specific CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to find the closest parent that contains the following css property:

```
background-image: url(*here goes a link to a valid image*);
```

Finding it could probably be done via selecting all elements, filtering them in an array, then using the first/last element of the array, but I'd like to know if there's a faster way to select the closest parent that fulfills the requirement I mentioned before, like this:

```
<parent1 style="background-image:url(http://google.com/images/photo.png);">
        <parent2 style="background-image:url('http://google.com/images/photo.png');">
                <mydiv></mydiv>
        </parent2>
</parent1>
```

I want the parent2 selected;

Keep in mind that I do not know the **background url**.

Comment: What did you with "first parent"? The most inner one? Or the most outer one?

Comment: @feeela the closest parent to the child.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the jQuery selector to allow for this. And with your specific rules.

Something like this:

```js
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  backgroundValid: function(a) {
    //change the url for what you want
    return $(a).css('background-image') === "url(http://stacksnippets.net/validurl)";
  }
});

var test = $('.foo').closest('div:backgroundValid');

console.log(test) //prints bar
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url('validurl');">
  <div class="bar" style="background-image:url('validurl');">
    <div class="foo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to filter all parents, just make it recursive like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iredjee/6uxrutzz/6/)

**html**

```
<div id="parent1" style="background-image:url(validurl);">
    <div id="parent2" style="background-image:url(validurl);">
        <div id="start"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var cssKey = "background-image";
    var element = $('#start');
    var found = false;
    while (!found) {
        element = element.parent();
        found = element.css(cssKey) == 'none' ? false : true;
        if (element.is($('html'))) break;
    }
    if (found) {
        console.log(element.attr('id'));
    } else {
        console.log('Not found');
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not know the background image url, but the parent must have it as a value.

Comment: You mean that it's enough if parent has background image url and no matter what the value is. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that exactly. I don't care what the value inside the url will be because it will probably be a link to an image. But the "background-image" property is a must.

Comment: I updated answer and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iredjee/6uxrutzz/6). It completely solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can help you,

1. select the element
2. pick up all its parent
3. filter its parent by what you want!

```js
var firstParent, URL_TO_MATCH = "url(HELLO WORLD)";

$('#foo').parents().filter(function() {
  var isValid = $(this).css('background-image') == URL_TO_MATCH;
  

   if(!firstParent && isValid) {
     firstParent = $(this);
   }
  
   return isValid;
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't find the *first parent* as requested in the question, but *all* the parents. Also take notice that 'HELLO WORLD' should be replaced with 'url(http://example.com/validurl)' and not just the url.

Comment: This is just a starter point, you need to improve the below snippet...
For example, instead of using === operator you should use a regular_expression in order to handle caseSensitive or CaseInsensitive issue, or, for example, to handle **'** instead of **"**